# How can I convert tickLower.price0 and tickLower.price1 of subgraphs V3?

Tags: uniswapv3

I am using subgraphs from Uniswap V3, and I am trying to get the MaxPrice and MinPrice from the position results.

here is my query;

https://api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/uniswap/uniswap-v3

```
query GetPositions($walletAddress: ID!) {
  positions(where: { owner: $walletAddress }) {
    id
    owner
    tickUpper {
      price0
      price1
    }
    tickLower {
      price0
      price1
    }
    token0 {
      id
      name
      symbol
      decimals
    }
    token1 {
      id
      name
      symbol
      decimals
    }
    pool {
      sqrtPrice
    }
  }
}
```

the prices (tickLower.price0, tickLower.price1) is a BigDecimal. so, how can I convert it to the price as the Uniswap site? (like the figure below.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use

```
.toString()
```

each tick will have two prices

price of token0 in token1

and

price of token1 in token0